# It isn't clear what objects of $\mathbb{C}[x_{1},\dots,x_{n}]$ and $\dfrac{\mathbb{C}[x_{1},\dots,x_{n}]}{\mathbb{I}(V)}$ are isomorphic to me.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Page 22 of Smith. An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry says that "Obviously, restriction defines a surjective ring homomorphism $\mathbb{C}[x_{1},\dots,x_{n}] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}[x_{1},\dots,x_{n}]|_{V}$ with kernel precisely the ideal of functions $\mathbb{I}(V)$ vanishing on $V$. So the coordinate ring $\mathbb{C}[x_{1},\dots,x_{n}]|_{V}$ is isomorphic to the ring $\dfrac{\mathbb{C}[x_{1},\dots,x_{n}]}{\mathbb{I}(V)}$ in a natural way. Equivalence classes in $\mathbb{C}(V)$ correspond to functions on $V$."

The ring homomorphism has a kernel that is mapped to $0$ yet the isomorphism appears to be between equivalence classes of functions that have the same value restricted to $V$. What objects are isomorphic between the two rings and can I have another example of two such isomorphic objects?

Comment: What is isomorphic are the *rings*, not their elements.

Comment: I do not understand how that is.

Comment: Do you know what it means for two rings to be isomorphic?

Comment: Do you mean how they are algebras that contain $\mathbb{C}$ as subrings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R = \mathbb C[x_1, ... , x_n]$.  They are thinking of $R$ in two ways, first as an abstract ring, and second as a ring of polynomial functions $\mathbb C^n \rightarrow \mathbb C$.  It is in the second way that they are making sense of $R|_V$.  By definition, $R|_V$ is the ring of functions $V \rightarrow \mathbb C$ obtained by restricting polynomial functions $\mathbb C^n \rightarrow \mathbb C$ to $V$.

For $R|_V$, you don't have to worry about equivalence classes of functions.  The elements of $R|_V$ are literally functions from $V$ to $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Then the quotient ring has the element $0$ in it, and the coordinate ring has functions that would equal to $0$ on the variety. Without equivalence classes, how can I make the map between those functions in the coordinate ring that vanish and $0$ in the quotient ring both 1 to 1 and onto?

Comment: You understand the zero element of $R|_V$ is just the function $V \rightarrow \mathbb C$ which sends every element of $V$ to $0 \in \mathbb C$, right?

Comment: Well the text says the kernel is the ideal of functions vanishing (everywhere) on $V$, I didn't know about the other functions with the same restriction such as $x+1$ and $2$ restricted to the variety $\mathbb{V}(x-1)$. Other than that the difference should just be that 1 is restricted to the variety and the quotient is not restricted to the variety.

Comment: That's right, the obvious map from $R$ (as a ring of polynomials) to $R|_V$ (the ring of polynomial functions from $V$ to $\mathbb C$) is surjective and its kernel is clearly $I(V)$.